# An error occurred while reading the value from the stream object. Error: "java.io.IOException: Protocol violation: [ 14, 115, ]"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

This below snippet is throwing protocol violation error with MS SQL Server database using MS SQL Serer JDBC type 4 driver.  I'm using SQL Server db version as 12.00.6372, driver version as 4.0.2206.100  and
Driverclass as com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. Also tried with latest JDBC driver  'mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar' but there is no difference. Do you think its product issue? I will greatly appreciate if you can let me know if there is hot fix related to it with SQLServer?

Error:

> ErrorCode is 0 Message is An error occurred while reading the value
> from the stream object. Error: "java.io.IOException: Protocol
> violation: [ 14, 115, ]"

```
boolean insertStatusFlag=false;
        
        String SqlInsertQry = "INSERT INTO Content(CreateDate, Content, processFlag) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        

        System.out.println(new StringBuffer("ContentID is ").append(strContentID).toString());
        System.out.println("It's preparing to insert content into Content table");
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try{
            System.out.println(new StringBuffer("SQL Query is ").append(SqlInsertQry).toString());
            ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(SqlInsertQry);
            System.out.println("It's passing the value to the parameter 'CreateDate' as SQLTimeStamp object ");
            ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
            System.out.println("It's passing the value to the parameter 'Content' as reader object");
            ps.setCharacterStream(2,new InputStreamReader(isContent),-1);
            System.out.println("It's passing the value to the parameter 'processFlag' as 'false' string object");
            ps.setString(3, "false");
            System.out.println("It's attempting to execute the insert statement");
            int updateCount=ps.executeUpdate();
            if (updateCount==1){
                insertStatusFlag=true;
                System.out.println("Inserting Content into Content table was successful!!");
            }else{
                errorMessage="Inserting Content into Content table was failed";
            }
            ps.close();
            System.out.println(new StringBuffer("Statement update count is ").append(updateCount).toString());                          
        }catch(SQLException sqe){
            insertStatusFlag=false;
            System.out.println("new StringBuffer("SQLException is occured while it's inserting Content into Content table, ErrorCode is ").append(sqe.getErrorCode()).append(" Message is ").append(sqe.getMessage()).toString());
            errorMessage=new StringBuffer("SQLException was thrown while it was inserting Content into Content table,").append( " ErrorCode ").append(sqe.getErrorCode()).append(" SQLState:").append(sqe.getSQLState()).append("Message ").append(sqe.getMessage()).toString();
        }finally{           
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException se1) {
                    errorMessage=new StringBuffer("SQLException was thrown while it was closing the prepared statement object,").append( " ErrorCode ").append(se1.getErrorCode()).append(" SQLState:").append(se1.getSQLState()).append("Message ").append(se1.getMessage()).toString();
                    errorTrace(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error message with stack trace? That protocol violation message looks like something oracle.jdbc.driver would throw.

Comment: This was not throwing from oracle but from SQL server. Below is error message that I get from code when I try to run it.  ErrorCode 0 SQLState:22000Message An error occurred while reading the value from the stream object. Error: "java.io.IOException: Protocol violation: [ 14, 115, ]" .

Comment: Sorry, Input stream object was a refenced stream objectto  Clob based data from oracle database. It misled as failure happened when it called executeUpdate on SQLServer query. I fixed it by upgrading my recent oracle driver. Thanks